# Sync on associations Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, synchronization, sequelize.js

Currently sequelize tries to create the tables every time I start the application, I have already switched to sync ({force: false}) and even then it still tries to create, I believe it is something related to associations.

My code:

```
const config = server.src.libs.config
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(
        config.database,
        config.username,
        config.password,
        config.params
    )
    db = {
        sequelize,
        Sequelize,
        models: {}
    }
    const dir = path.join('../src/models')
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
        const modelDir = path.join(dir, file)
        const model = sequelize.import(modelDir)
        model.sync({force: false})
        db.models[model.name] = model
    })
    Object.keys(db.models).forEach(key => {
        if (db.models[key].hasOwnProperty('associate')){
            db.models[key].associate(db.models);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Have you tried sequelize,sync() function after registering all models and associations?

Comment: I found my error, in start of sequelize i use sequelize.sync().done() to start the aplicattion, but if i delete sync(), the code dont run